# How to enable and disable the reader for the blind?

Tags: desktop-apps

I know that in ubuntu are different facilities for the blind.

How to enable and disable the reader for the blind in Ubuntu?

I mean the reader who pronounce what you have clicked on the keyboard and what is under the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open menu, search for `System Settings`, look for `Universal Access` and then you can enable `Screen Reader` option by clicking on the switch.

Unfortunately, if workspaces option is enabled you **can't** use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, unless you change keyboard shortcut settings in the keyboard settings menu.

Hope this can help you.

[image: screen reader settings]